# Firebase Authentication in a React Chrome Extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a chrome extension with react. In order to achieve online functionality, I'm using Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Authentication.

However, when logging users in with Firebase Auth, it calls external scripts.

In order to work around this, I have to use manifest version 2 - but I would prefer to use v3 for additional functionality.

Is there any way to get around the Firebase-React external scripts? Or do I have to use Manifest V2?